# saving attendance register records logic with mysql and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, logic

I'm designing an attendance register system which will display all 'gymnasts' from the value set in a 'select class' dropdown with their own checkbox (Displaying this using AJAX and JSON). Which is all 'hunky dory'.

Pseudo Form:

```
<form>
<classes dropdown populated from classes table onchange="ajaxFunction()">
<save button>
</form>
```

Pseudo AJAX response: form elements of gymnasts with checkboxes next to them.

```
GymnastName    [Checkbox]
GymnastName    [Checkbox]
GymnastName    [Checkbox]
GymnastName    [Checkbox]
GymnastName    [Checkbox]
GymnastName    [Checkbox]
```

The user would then check the boxes of all the gymnasts that are present, and leave the boxes for the gymnasts that are absent.

Upon hitting the save button; I'm not sure how to go about saving each gymnast's presence as a single record in the class-attendance table:

class-attendance(id, classid, gymnastid, present[y/n],datetime)

I understand that this may not be the best way to approach the problem, however is there some way to create an array for the data contained in the form so that it can be inserted into the class-attendance table with each gymnast's presence being saved as a record?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Presumably you only store those who were present?!?

Comment: @Strawberry Keeping a record of absence is just as important as presence.  So thanks for your 'helpful' comment.

Comment: Thanks for your sarcasm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i understand according to that i have made script using HTML,Jquery and PHP. See the code is work for you or not.

HTML and Jquery Code

```
    <form action="process.php"  method="post">

<div>  
GymnastName  <input type="checkbox"  class="atd" ><br>
 <!-- put gymnastid in value what you getting from JSON -->
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_id[]" value='1' class="atdid">
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_attend[]" value='n' class="atdval">  
</div><br>

<div>
GymnastName  <input type="checkbox"  class="atd"> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_id[]" value='2' class="atdid">
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_attend[]"  value='n' class="atdval">  
</div><br>

<div>
GymnastName  <input type="checkbox"  class="atd"> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_id[]" value='3' class="atdid">
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_attend[]" value='n'class="atdval">    
</div><br>

<div>
GymnastName  <input type="checkbox"  class="atd"> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_id[]" value='4' class="atdid">   
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_attend[]" value='n'class="atdval">    
</div><br>

<div>
GymnastName  <input type="checkbox"  class="atd"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_id[]" value='5' class="atdid">  
<input type="hidden" name="Gymnast_attend[]" value='n' class="atdval">  
</div><br>
  <input type="submit" name="Save">
</form>

<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.atd').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(this).closest('div').find('.atdval').val('y'); 
        }
        else{

            $(this).closest('div').find('.atdval').val('n');
        }        
    });
});

<script>
```

PHP CODE (process.php)

```
<?php
$Gymnast_id=$_POST['Gymnast_id'];
$Gymnast_attend=$_POST['Gymnast_attend'];
foreach ($Gymnast_id as $key => $id) {

echo "Id: ".$id."<br>";
echo "Attend: ".$Gymnast_attend[$key]."<br><hr>";

// here you get id of Gymnast and present status, default it is "n"
// you can add your sql query here
//class-attendance(id, classid, gymnastid, present[y/n],datetime) 
}
?>
```

Comment: So you can post arrays as postdata?  That's awesome!

Comment: Yes we can do dear :)